# Matrix via `np.fromfunction`

Tags: python, numpy

When I try to run my code, I get this problem:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I cannot understand what and where exactly I should change to fix the problem.

```py
import numpy as np

n = int(input("Enter the value of n for the nxn matrix: "))

a=np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: n if i==j else (i+1) + (j+1) , (n,n), dtype=int)
print(a)
```

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `lambda i, j: n if i==j else (i+1) + (j+1)`, what do you think will be the values of `i` and `j` each time the `lambda` gets used? How many times do you think it will be used? Why? Did you try to read the documentation, in order to understand how `np.fromfunction` works?

Comment: Exactly what do you want to happen when the code runs? What should be the resulting value of `a`, for an example `n` value? More importantly: **is this a question** about how `np.fromfunction` works, or is it a question about how to get the result you want?

Comment: The result should be a matrix in which the diagonal numbers are equal to the `n` integer that was input by the user, while other numbers in the matrix are equal to `(i+1) + (j+1)`. My concern is what I should change in the code to make it run.

Comment: What's so important about using `fromfunction`?  To use it, your function has to work with arrays, as shown in the answer. Instead you've written a function that works with scalar inputs.

Comment: Did you pay attention to the error traceback?  You should have included that in your question.  It clearly shows that `fromfunction` calls `np.indices` and passes that to your function.  I added a duplicate that tries to describe that action in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're assuming that your function is being called `n * n` times, each time with a new pair of possible indices 0..n. Try printing the values to see what's going on:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> n = 3
>>> def f(i, j):
...     print(i)
...     print(j)
...     return n if i==j else (i+1) + (j+1)

>>> np.fromfunction(f, (n,n), dtype=int)
[[0 0 0]
 [1 1 1]
 [2 2 2]]
[[0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "...\Python\Python311\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 1866, in fromfunction
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in f
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Instead, the function is being called just once with a meshgrid of the possible indices!

In the `... if i == j else ...` part, after `i` and `j` have been compared, you're left with a boolean array with both True and False values, so numpy is unsure what to do.

---

Instead, rely on [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for this kind of `if-else` logic, and possibly use a little bit of broadcasting for efficiency:

```
>>> xs, ys = np.indices((n, n), sparse=True)
>>> np.where(np.eye(n), n, xs + ys + 2)
array([[5, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [3, 5, 5, 6, 7],
       [4, 5, 5, 7, 8],
       [5, 6, 7, 5, 9],
       [6, 7, 8, 9, 5]])
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I am worried is it possible to create a matrix using exactly `np.fromfunction()` or not.

Comment: @LordPol Sure, but you end up with essentially the same `np.where` construct inside your lambda, which `np.fromfunction` then calls: `np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: np.where(i == j, n, i + j + 2), (n, n), dtype=int)`.